# how to create folder in phone memory and save images.

Tags: android

how to create new folder "MyFolder" in phone memory and save all captured images on that folder?
Please help me. The following code save all images to Phone's default Image gallery. I want to create new folder and save all captured images on that folder. what should I do?

```
    public class PhotoCaptureExample extends Activity 
  {
protected Button _button;
protected ImageView _image;
protected TextView _field;
protected String _path;
protected boolean _taken;

protected static final String PHOTO_TAKEN   = "photo_taken";

 @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
 {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    _image = ( ImageView ) findViewById( R.id.image );
    _field = ( TextView ) findViewById( R.id.field );
    _button = ( Button ) findViewById( R.id.button );
    _button.setOnClickListener( new ButtonClickHandler() );
   ;
  _path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/myfolder   
 /"+System.currentTimeMillis()+".jpg";




    File dir = new File(_path );
    try{
      if(dir.mkdir()) {
         System.out.println("Directory created");
      } 
      else {
         System.out.println("Directory is not created");
      }}
      catch(Exception e){

    }  



















}

public class ButtonClickHandler implements View.OnClickListener 
{
    public void onClick( View view ){
        Log.i("MakeMachine", "ButtonClickHandler.onClick()" );
        startCameraActivity();
    }
}

protected void startCameraActivity()
{
    Log.i("MakeMachine", "startCameraActivity()" );
    File file = new File( _path );
    Uri outputFileUri = Uri.fromFile( file );

    Intent intent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE );
    intent.putExtra( MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, outputFileUri );

    startActivityForResult( intent, 0 );
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) 
{   
    Log.i( "MakeMachine", "resultCode: " + resultCode );
    switch( resultCode )
    {
        case 0:
            Log.i( "MakeMachine", "User cancelled" );
            break;

        case -1:
            onPhotoTaken();
            break;
    }
}

protected void onPhotoTaken()
{
    Log.i( "MakeMachine", "onPhotoTaken" );

    _taken = true;

    BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    options.inSampleSize = 4;

    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile( _path, options );

    _image.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

    _field.setVisibility( View.GONE );
}

@Override 
protected void onRestoreInstanceState( Bundle savedInstanceState){
    Log.i( "MakeMachine", "onRestoreInstanceState()");
    if( savedInstanceState.getBoolean( PhotoCaptureExample.PHOTO_TAKEN ) ) {
        onPhotoTaken();
    }
}

@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState( Bundle outState ) {
    outState.putBoolean( PhotoCaptureExample.PHOTO_TAKEN, _taken );
}
}
```

Comment: Check and verify it will create duplicate images in your Phone default Image gellery and the path you supplied into camera intent.

Comment: tell me how i create new folder? i dnr wana save in phne default gallery

Comment: is your code not able to generate new folder called 'myfolder'?

Comment: yes no folder genrate also tell me what permissions i used in manifies?

Comment: have you tried with the given solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need Following permissions in your manifest file to create folder.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/> 
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
```

UPDATED :

```
package com.test;

import java.io.File;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;


public class CameraTest extends Activity 
{
    protected Button _button;
    protected ImageView _image;
    protected TextView _field;
    protected String _path;
    protected boolean _taken;

protected static final String PHOTO_TAKEN   = "photo_taken";

 @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
 {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.camtest);

    _image = ( ImageView ) findViewById( R.id.image );
    _field = ( TextView ) findViewById( R.id.field );
    _button = ( Button ) findViewById( R.id.button );
    _button.setOnClickListener( new ButtonClickHandler() );
   // _path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/NewFolder/"+System.currentTimeMillis()+".jpg";

    _path = "/sdcard/NewFolder/test1.jpg";


    String dir = "/sdcard/NewFolder/";
    File imageDirectory = new File(dir);
    imageDirectory.mkdirs();

   /* File dir = new File(_path );
    try{
      if(dir.mkdir()) {
         System.out.println("Directory created");
      } 
      else {
         System.out.println("Directory is not created");
      }}
      catch(Exception e){

    }  */
}

public class ButtonClickHandler implements View.OnClickListener 
{
    public void onClick( View view ){
        Log.i("MakeMachine", "ButtonClickHandler.onClick()" );
        startCameraActivity();
    }
}

protected void startCameraActivity()
{
    Log.i("MakeMachine", "startCameraActivity()" );
    File file = new File( _path );
    Uri outputFileUri = Uri.fromFile( file );

    Intent intent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE );
    intent.putExtra( MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, outputFileUri );

    startActivityForResult( intent, 0 );
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) 
{   
    Log.i( "MakeMachine", "resultCode: " + resultCode );
    switch( resultCode )
    {
        case 0:
            Log.i( "MakeMachine", "User cancelled" );
            break;

        case -1:
            onPhotoTaken();
            break;
    }
}

protected void onPhotoTaken()
{
    Log.i( "MakeMachine", "onPhotoTaken" );

    _taken = true;

    BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    options.inSampleSize = 4;

    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile( _path, options );

    _image.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

    _field.setVisibility( View.GONE );
}


}
```

This works perfectly for me.

Check out with this code.

Hope this helps you.

Thanks.

Comment: i did this  and a folder create in my SD card HEllo World bt image not save there  is save on phone image gellery

 protected void startCameraActivity()
    {
     Log.i("MakeMachine", "startCameraActivity()" );
   
     
     
     File directory = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+File.separator+"helloworld");
        directory.mkdirs();
     
     Intent intent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE );
     intent.putExtra( MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT,directory );     
     startActivityForResult( intent, 0 );
    }

Comment: Look at the edited solution I have posted. It works well and I can see folder created and image is also stored in that folder. And finally I will have captured image in the used imageview.

Comment: What if i have a device without sdcard slot. I have an view and want to create a folder and save the image in phone memory. Please help  me out

Answer (score 0):

Check if this could help,

```
File mydir = context.getDir("mydir", Context.MODE_PRIVATE); //Creating an internal dir;
File fileWithinMyDir = new File(mydir, "myfile"); //Getting a file within the dir.
FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(fileWithinMyDir); //Use the stream as usual to write into the file.
```

Comment: what i write in this code then

Uri outputFileUri = Uri.fromFile( file );

Comment: use applications's context instead.

Answer (score -1):

The code should can use, but should pay attention to create this directory first.